# Can we use some conditional formula in rule trigger date?

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Can we use some conditional formula in rule trigger date?
Let’s say we have a custom object having a date field. This custom object will have multiple records (let’s say R1,R2,R3,R4) with its own date field value. Now can we fire an email alert from workflow rule based on the date field value of R1 (after 7 days) and for R2(after 30 days) etc.

Answer (score 2):

I remember being able to do that. You need an extra custom field that holds the value for the trigger date, then have the rule trigger date to use that field.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Time-Dependent Workflow Actions to be based on a Date field in the object. Below is a screenshot demonstrating the rules you defined above:

[image]